# If I place an object in an array at index 0 how do I place the object that was there into index 1?

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I am in a beginner's Java class. I only know basic Java. We just started polymorphism and Inheritance. My problem is placing objects into an array. I have an array of ten `Runner` objects as follows.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Race 
{

    public static void main(String []args)
    {

        Runner r1 = new Runner("Jack Sprat", 10);
        Runner r2 = new Runner("Cecil Litwack", 8);
        Runner r3 = new Runner("Dina Might", 3);
        Runner r4 = new Runner("Seymour Butts", 4);
        Runner r5 = new Runner("Ima reject", 1 );
        Runner r6 = new Runner("Ivan Earache", 9);
        Runner r7 = new Runner("Ace Ventura", 6);
        Runner r8 = new Runner("Joan O'Farc", 7);
        Runner r9 = new Runner("Jack O'Lantern", 5);
        Runner r10 = new Runner("Jim Nasium", 2);

        Runner[] raceArray = new Runner[10];

        raceArray[0] = r1;
        raceArray[1] = r2;
        raceArray[2] = r3;
        raceArray[3] = r4;
        raceArray[4] = r5;
        raceArray[5] = r6;
        raceArray[6] = r7;
        raceArray[7] = r8;
        raceArray[8] = r9;
        raceArray[9] = r10;
```

Let's say I want to place the object at index `1` into index `0`, will the object at index `0` go to index `1`? Or will the object at index `0` be removed from the array? If it is removed how do I make it to when I place an object at a different array index the objects just trade places in the array?

Comment: With `Lists`, you can remove items from the list and insert them at arbitrary positions in the list. Arrays are very poorly suited to this task.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you do not *store* objects into arrays, you store **references to objects** in an array.

In case you later set `raceArray[0] = raceArray[1];` from now on the zero-th and first item in `raceArray` will both *refer* to `r2`. It means that `r1` is no longer references from that array. That does not necessary means `r1` is gone since other things can stil refer to it.

In order to *swap* places, you can use the following code:

```
Runner temp = raceArray[0];
raceArray[0] = raceArray[1];
raceArray[1] = temp;
```

What you do is you create a `temp` - a temporary variable - that refers to the same object as does the array at index `0`, next you *overwrite* index `0` with the reference at index `1`, finally you overwrite index `1` with the value in `temp`.

Comment: That was because we are both great. Oh, and because that's how `swap` works. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Arrays contains references to objects. So when you'll execute `raceArray[0] = raceArray[1]` both memory segments will contain a reference to the same `r2` object.